# Spring @PropertySource, how to read a file not on the classpath, but under WEB-INF

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, properties-file

Spring version `4.2.2`: What would be the Java Config replacement for the following:

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/conf/mars.properties" />
</bean>
```

I have the following in one of the Config. files:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource("file:WEB-INF/conf/mars.properties")
public class JpaConfig {

private static final String DB_DRIVER = "a";
private static final String DB_URL = "b";    
private static final String DB_USERNAME = "c";
private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "d";
private static final String DB_PLATFORM = "e";

@Resource
private Environment env;

@Bean(destroyMethod="close")
public DataSource dataSource() {
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();

p.setUrl(env.getProperty(DB_URL));
p.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty(DB_DRIVER));
p.setUsername(env.getProperty(DB_USERNAME));
p.setPassword(env.getProperty(DB_PASSWORD));
....
}
```

This results in the following runtime error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \WEB-INF\conf\mars.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
```

I tried the following variations but to no avail:

```
@PropertySource("file://WEB-INF/conf/mars.properties")
```

This is an XML configured based application I'm converting to Java Config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is

```
@PropertySource("/WEB-INF/conf/mars.properties")
```

Spring will use `DefaultResourceLoader#getResource(String)`. For paths starting with `/`, this delegates to `getResourceByPath` which is overriden by `AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext` (the superclass of `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` which handles `@Configuration`).

This will then create a [`ServletContextResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletContextResource.html) which can successfully locate the resource relative to the servlet context.

Comment: Is it supposed to work that way with spring 3.2 ?
For me it keeps telling "class path resource [WEB-INF/properties/config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist" at boot time.  (Note : the leading slash is removed in the error message)

Comment: @baraber Typically WEB-INF is not added to the classpath. Move your properties files to something on the classpath or add WEB-INF to the classpath.